# Writing to HBase from Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

I have an input of files in Spark Streaming (using Scala) composed of (key,value) pairs, what I need to do is store the value in HBase if the key satisfies a certain condition.
since I have :

```
val pair: DStream[(String, String)]
```

what I tried to do is a condition inside a map and from there try to insert the value in HBase :

```
pair.map(x => {
if (x._1 == "condition")
{ val hconf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val hTable = new HTable(hconf, "mytab")
val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(1))
thePut.add(Bytes.toBytes("colfamily"), Bytes.toBytes("c1"), Bytes.toBytes(x._2)
hTable.put(thePut)
})
}
```

However this doesn't work and I get an error when excecuting with spark-submit saying : no output operations registered so nothing to execute

This is the only way that I can think of of inserting the values into HBase, am I doing anything wrong? Could you please help me fix it ?

Here is the updated code :

```
pair.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.map( p =>
{val hconf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
 val hTable = new HTable(hconf,"mytab")
 val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(1))
 thePut.add(Bytes.toBytes("colfamily"), Bytes.toBytes(p._1), Bytes.toBytes(p._2)
 hTable.put(thePut)
})
```

When I run it with Spark-submit, I get an error saying "Task not serializable" , do you know what it means and how I can fix it ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jean,

Reason why you are getting an error message is you are missing action on RDD named as *pair* in your code.

Refer below corrected code.

```
  pair.foreachRDD((rdd : [RDD(String,String)]) => {  
 val newRdd = rdd.map(p=> (p._1,p._2))
        if (mewRdd._1 == "condition")
        {
         /* Your code*/
        }})
```

To insert data in hbase from spark streaming refer this article https://www.mapr.com/blog/spark-streaming-hbase
I hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the rdd inside the foreachRDD is of type RDD[(String , String)] so I was not able to do rdd._1 directly, any idea how to access it ?

Comment: ok, then use this  pair.foreachRDD(rdd: RDD[(String, String)]) . it will work.

Comment: That's what I did, but when I try to do rdd._1 it's not there meaning rdd._1 can't be applied on an RDD[(String, String)] type but rather on (String, String)

Comment: can you try this, -->

pair.foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[(String, String)]) => {  
val newrdd = rdd.map( p=> (p._1,p._2))
    if (newrdd._1 == "condition")
   ......

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to factor the creation of the configuration and the table object out of the foreach? Or even, add some batching...

Comment: Yes, that's need to be.

Comment: @sandip44 now when I run spark-submit it gives me an error : 
Task not serializable

Comment: @DiegoSevilla Could you please explain what you mean by add some batching ?

Comment: OK. Now can you remove hbase code from "if" condition. And again run spark submit. So will understand that which code is not getting serialize new RDD or hbase code.

Comment: @sandip44 I continued reading the error and it says 
" Caused by : java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable, 
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable, value: mytab ....."

Comment: @sandip44 when I remove the HBAse code there is no more error .

Comment: OK that means pairRdd issue has resolved now. But as you have declared hbase configuration and htable inside foreach it giving serialization error. Just declare those things outside foreach loop

Comment: @sandip44 Same error even when I declare the HBase configuration outside the foreach

Comment: Jean refere this article for inserting data in hbase from spark streaming https://www.mapr.com/blog/spark-streaming-hbase

Comment: @sandip44 I thank you for your help and patience, I've seen this article and the difference resides in the structure of the .csv file , in my case there is only insertion in HBase inside the rdd not for the whole file, I think that's where the difficulty is..

Comment: @Jean, I mean using the batch API for accesing the HBase table https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table.html#batch%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Object[]%29